# join the Orion crew and service modules - Does it mean "connect the modules to make them as one"?

Tags: word-meaning

> NASA is preparing to **join the Orion crew and service modules** in
> the coming months ahead of Artemis II, the first crewed mission under
> Artemis. Technicians are welding subsystem components of the Artemis
> III crew module throughout the summer.

[Source: NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-invites-media-to-view-orion-spacecraft-for-next-artemis-missions)

The word "join" is not clear to me. "Join the crew" refers to "make you present with the people (the crew), yet  I see "modules" there it should have been "the crew module" - thus "joining" is an engineering thing to make the module go together. I am not very sure.

What does "join" mean here?

Comment: "Nasa is preparing to join the Orion crew and service **modules**" <<<--- note this last word is plural. It is talking about the modules being joined together - the Orion crew module and the service module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence says that NASA is going to **connect** the crew **module** and the service module.

*Crew* is being used like an adjective here to modify *module*, and in English, we often don't repeat a noun if it is being used with multiple adjectives, e.g.

- black and white cats (black cats and white cats)
- the old and the new administrations (the old administration and the new one)
  etc.

You are correct that "join the crew" usually means "become a member of the crew", but in this case you have to read it in context.  It wouldn't make sense for NASA (the entire organization) to join the crew of the Orion (which doesn't even exist yet).

The sentence could have been written more clearly, since "join the crew" can mean "become a member of the crew" and "service modules" can mean "perform maintenance on modules", but context is key.

Comment: +1 Another clue is the word "welding"